# "Я не могу тебе помочь" — "Ладно"

Tags: этикет

Если вам отказали в просьбе, можете ли вы ответить: "ну ладно", или лучше "хорошо"? Содержит ли "ладно" всегда и во всех случаях оттенок снисходительности или он может использоваться и в значении не снисходительного, а кроткого примирения: "Ну что ж, так и быть"? Если, к примеру, такая реплика адресована преподавателю в ответ на домашнее задание: "хорошо", "ладно" — не будет ли это проявлением фамильярности?

Comment: Думаю, Владимир, что вот здесь "не" надо написать раздельно (имеется противопоставление): * в значении **не** снисходительного, **а** кроткого примирения*. (http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.53) И еще: тире обрамляется пробелами; в заголовке лучше использовать *ёлочки* (так мне когда-то рекомендовал модератор).

Comment: Ха-ха, отделил тире и сделал раздельное НЕ во второй "присест", а потом решил почитать, что ты, Римма, пишешь, и оказалось, что как раз об этом же.)))

Answer (score 0):

"Хорошо" не совсем подходит, потому что ничего хорошего в отказе нет.

> или он может использоваться и в значении не снисходительного, а кроткого примирения: "Ну что ж, так и быть"?

Вполне (зависит от интонации). Оно как бы и используется, когда человек принимает сказанное. А вот "ну и ладно" — нет, передаёт недовольство и то, что как-нибудь обойдутся.

Преподавателю так говорить не стоит (нетактично), это употребляется, когда люди на равных.

Comment: А как отвечать, когда преподаватель даёт задание на дом?

Comment: Когда преподаватель отказывается помочь с д/з? Можно сказать "жаль". Преподаватель как бы обязан разъяснить то, что не ясно, но не решать же ему самому задание. Фраза "не могу помочь" как бы намекает на его некомпетентность, что он сам не разбирается и не может решить задание. Но он может сказать "не хочу подсказывать".

Comment: Нет, я про обыкновенную дачу домашнего задания: когда преподаватель просто перечисляет задания, а студент выражает понимание.

Comment: Ну тогда "хорошо" подходит. А если "ну ладно", то не всё устраивает, но всё-таки соглашается (но опять же последний абзац ответа).

Comment: Если уж выражает понимание, то "ясно". А если "хорошо", то этим как бы выражает намерение выполнить задания. Ещё лучше ситуации соответствует слово "ок" (американское общеупотребительное выражение, ставшее **международным**).

Comment: Ещё можно слово "понял" (но оно своеобразное, подобно "принял").

Comment: А что, если сказать "ладно" — это не будет подобно "понял"? Представляю себе ситуацию, в которой оно не будет подразумевать, что учащегося "не всё устраивает".

Comment: Восклицательная интонация, выражающая ободрение, энтузиазм как будто позволяет употреблять "Ладно" без продолжения

Comment: Меняю комментарий. Тогда оно подобно "сделаю", как и "хорошо" в этой ситуации. А вот "понял" и "ясно" — не так, мог понять и ничего не выполнять. Обычно с продолжением, но при подходящей для согласия интонации можно и без. Но это слово для товарища, а не для преподавателя.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, следует описать разницу между использованием ‟да” и ‟ладно” и ‟хорошо”, так как она очень отчетлива, хотя и не относится к вопросу. ‟Да” нельзя ответить на повелительную просьбу, как: ‟Вынеси мусор”, а только на вопрос, как: ‟Ты вынесешь мусор?” В то время как ‟ладно” и ‟хорошо” можно ответить как на повелительную просьбу, так и на вопрос: ‟Вынеси мусор. — Ладно / хорошо”, ‟Ты вынесешь мусор? — Ладно / хорошо”.

Что касается разницы между ‟ладно” и ‟хорошо”. Эта разница такая, как вы и написали: ‟хорошо” — согласие выполнить повелительную просьбу или приказ, ‟ладно” — согласие выполнить повелительную просьбу или приказ, но вопреки нежеланию делать это (согласие из-за моральных принципов, должностных обязательств, долга и т.д.).

Вот несколько примеров иллюстрирующих это:

> Мультфильм ‟Шрек”. Осел навязывает свою компанию Шрэку, Шрэку это не нравится, он всячески противится этой компании. Они заходят в дом Шрэка, и происходит следующий диалог:
> — И именно поэтому нам с тобой просто необходимо держаться друг друга. Позволь мне остаться! Пожалуйста! Пожалуйста!
> — Ладно! Ладно! Но только на одну ночь.
> — О! Благодарю тебя!
> (Данный диалог демонстрирует то, что Шрек, вопреки нежеланию, позволяет ослу остаться.)

> Фильм ‟Отель Гранд Будапешт”. Подчиненный подходит к владельцу отеля и начинает следующий диалог:
> — Простите. Явилась полиция. Хотят видеть вас.
> — Скажи, что я сейчас приду.
> — Хорошо.
> (Обратите внимание на то, что здесь подчиненный не мог сказать ‟ладно”, так как это указало бы на согласие на нежелательное действие. Это, кстати, и ответ на ваш вопрос про ответ школьника учителю.)

Также следует упомянуть, что при наличии нежелания человек всё же может употребить ‟хорошо”, так как необязательно демонстрировать то, что соглашается он вопреки нежеланию.

Что касается, как вы написали, кроткого примирения, то действие вопреки нежеланию может включать и такое.

Что касается ответа на отказ, то зависит от ситуации, от того, что вы хотите выразить в ответ на отказ.

Вот напоследок еще пример из Шрека:

> Сказочных созданий переселили в болота Шрека, и тот недоволен. Происходит следующий диалог:
> — Мы были вынуждены прийти сюда.
> — Кто заставил вас сделать это?
> — Лорд Фарквед.Он сопел, угрожал, а еще он подписал приказ о нашем изгнании.
> [ Вздыхает ] (Обратите внимание на этот вздох, который отчетливо демонстрирует согласие вопреки нежеланию.)
> —Ладно. Кто знает, где живет этот парень?

Comment: То есть если мне отказали (может, даже резковато) и я не хочу показать человеку огорчение, потому что он имел право отказать, я скажу: "Хорошо"? Не хочется в подобных случаях так отвечать...

Comment: В таких случаях вообще всё будет пониматься отказывающим в зависимости от ситуации. Он будет понимать градуальность огорчения вне зависимости от слов.  Если человек захочет указать на недовольство, то он  сделает это не подбором слов, а скорее интонацией, мимикой, словами об огорчении или действиями после того, как услышит отказ.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о рабочих отношениях, то можно отвечать "хорошо" или "вас понял". Это связано со значением *хорошо* в рамках субординации начальник-подчиненный. Начальник, тот кто оказывает милость или позволение, дает добро, независимо от того дает он его или нет возможность подчиненному делать что-то, он находится на стороне "добра", так как вы обращаетесь с просьбой, и "хорошо" означает согласие с его лидерством.

Слово *ладно* - русское и народное, ввиду того, что в народе не принято было обращаться к людям на "Вы", а принято было на "ты", слово *ладно* относится не в "вы", а к "мы" - мы действуем слаженно, ладно, в ладу друг с другом. *Ладно* можно отвечать близким людям при личных контактах:

-Ты пойдешь со мной в магазин?

-Не-а.

-Ладно, тогда я один, - пойду сам с собой, буду ладить с собой а не с тобой, пойду в ладу с собой.

-Не ладно, прохладно!

-Почему?

-Сам знаешь, - то есть ответчик может продолжить опровергнув "ладно" со своей стороны, а *хорошо/хорошо как скажешь* не может, потому что ему придется опровергать свои собственные слова, быть не в ладу с собой.

В общении с педагогом слово "ладно" может звучать фамильярно, так как вы не стоите на одном с ним уровне, не относитесь к его "фамилии" или не равны по статусу, не являетесь "мы". Слово "хорошо" звучит допустимо, как согласие с волей другого, ну или пишите: "хорошо, вас понял". Писать в ответ нужно, так как это тоже в рамках субординации. При общении с подчиненным, субъект должен утвердительно ответить, что понял/принял поручение или обстоятельства дела, а если у него проблемы с пониманием, также желательно повторить всё обстоятельство дела, и ответ может звучать так: "раз вы не сможете помочь, тогда больше вопросов нет, хорошо/спасибо".